# Size of output of a Conv1D layer in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to understand the output of a 1D convolution layer applied on a number of batches (3 in this case) of 2D input shapes (6x6).

The output of the code below is `(4, 10, 32)`. This answer is quite straight-forward for the first 2 indices.

- (4) We plug in N examples, we get out N examples.
- (8) When doing the convolution between a (10, 128) * (3, 1) and because the default padding is set to "valid", two of the values in our input space won't be mapped to our final result, that's why we get 8.
- I don't understand why the layer outputs 32 as the final index. What is the actual role of the `filters` argument in the Conv1D layer? It's not really intuitive for me how does the layer operates the final output as stated by the phrase down below.

**By the documentation this should be the output shape**

> Output shape: 3+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (new_steps, filters) steps value might have changed due to padding or strides.

```
input_shape = (4, 10, 128)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(
    32, 3, input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
print(y.shape) # (4, 10, 32)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two first statement are correct. The filter can be seen as the number of time you'll performe convolution over the series.

In the following [picture](https://peltarion.com/knowledge-center/documentation/modeling-view/build-an-ai-model/blocks/1d-convolution-block), you can see the operation performed. The left object represents your input, the middle one your kernel (of size (3,1)) and the right one your output.

[image]

- In your case, **if your number of filters is equal to 1**, you generate **128 kernels** of **size 3** which browse your series.
- For **each** kernel, it processes the convolution operation : multiplies kernel values with series values and sums the 3 products.
- Then the **128 results** are summed up.
- If you set your **number of filter equal to 32**, you operate this **whole operation 32 times**.
- As a result the number of parameters for Conv1D (without biases) is : kernel_size * input_depth * number_filters = **3 * 128 * 32** = 12,288.
- With biases, you add the number of filters to your previous result (12,288 + 32 = 12320).

So, the number of filters is the number of time this operation is processed. The outputs are then stacked and the process is repeated with the next convolutional layer.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any representation to well understand conv1D. This [one](https://indoml.com/2018/03/07/student-notes-convolutional-neural-networks-cnn-introduction/), for Conv2D, explains the process which is the same for Conv1D. (With inuth_depth = 3 and the number_filters = output_depth = 2)

[image]

Comment: It does make sense, the analogy to 2D helped me. Thanks!

Comment: input_shape = (1, 6, 6, 3);
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape);
print(x.shape);
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size = 3, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='valid',input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x);
print(y.shape); # THIS EXPLAINS THE 2D EXAMPLE